# I want numbers to be displayed in a text view from a dialog which appear when clicked on text view

Tags: java, android, dialog

```
public void goldWeight(){
    Dialog dialog = new Dialog(HomeActivity.this);
    dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_LEFT_ICON);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.gold_w_grm);
    dialog.setTitle("GOLD WEIGHT[Grams]");
    dialog.setCancelable(true);

    NumberPicker np1=(NumberPicker)dialog.findViewById(R.id.grm);
    np1.setMaxValue(9999);
    np1.setMinValue(0000);
    int grams = np1.getValue();

    NumberPicker np2=(NumberPicker)dialog.findViewById(R.id.mgrm);
    np2.setMaxValue(9999);
    np2.setMinValue(0000);
    int mgrams = np2.getValue();

    double gw;
    gw = grams+(mgrams/100f);
    String value = "" + gw;

    //value.toString();
    //String numberAsString = Double.toString(gw);
    TextView TV2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.UserGoldWeight);
    TV2.setText(value);
    //TV2.setText("hfhgf");
    dialog.show();
} //Layout for this Dialog      elativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/GoldWeightGrams"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<NumberPicker
    android:id="@+id/grm"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="false"
    android:layout_weight="1" />
<NumberPicker
    android:id="@+id/mgrm"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="120dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="false"
    android:layout_weight="1" />
```

Issue is program set 0.0 to text view when click on the view and fail to change it when dialog disappear. I want to get value from number pickers and show them in the text view when dialog disappear.

Comment: can you breakpoint or somehow check this `gw = grams+(mgrams/100f);` after you dismiss the dialog to check if it really has value after you pick from numberpicker

Comment: Yes, i did with toast but it also toasting the value when just click on text view, not when the value is set on number picker. it contains same value i.e 0.0

Comment: the number picker is in the dialog?

Comment: yes. it is in the dialog.

Comment: did you use any adapter or any to display the dialog?

Comment: No, i don't use adapters here.  things i used i mentioned their code here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

its not changed because you put the calculation before the NumberPicker change.

Try to put event on them

```
int grams, mgrams;
double gw;
TextView TV2;
public void goldWeight(){
    Dialog dialog = new Dialog(HomeActivity.this);
    dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_LEFT_ICON);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.gold_w_grm);
    dialog.setTitle("GOLD WEIGHT[Grams]");
    dialog.setCancelable(true);

    NumberPicker np1=(NumberPicker)dialog.findViewById(R.id.grm);
    np1.setMaxValue(9999);
    np1.setMinValue(0000);
    //set the last value
    np1.setValue(grams);

    NumberPicker np2=(NumberPicker)dialog.findViewById(R.id.mgrm);
    np2.setMaxValue(9999);
    np2.setMinValue(0000);
    //set the last value
    np2.setValue(mgrams);

    TV2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.UserGoldWeight);

    np1.setOnValueChangedListener(new NumberPicker.OnValueChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onValueChange(NumberPicker numberPicker, int i, int i1) {
            grams= numberPicker.getValue();
            changeTextView();
        }
    });
    np2.setOnValueChangedListener(new NumberPicker.OnValueChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onValueChange(NumberPicker numberPicker, int i, int i1) {
            mgrams= numberPicker.getValue();
            changeTextView();
        }
    });


    dialog.show();
}

void changeTextView(){
    //             mgrams/100f -> its float and not able to do more than 3 decimal number
    //gw = grams+(mgrams/100f);
    gw = grams+(((double)mgrams)/10000);
    //to be precise, convert it to decimal format (rounding), already tested and works perfectly on my device
    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.####");
    df.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.CEILING);

    String value = "" + df.format(gw);
    TV2.setText(value);
}
```

Comment: Great, it works budy but there is still one problem. program have to show only that value which is set on number picker but here it showing different value. it looks like adding some previous value to it.

Comment: and what to do if the last set value have to show on number pickers in when next time dialog open to set values ?

Comment: in ur case, because u open it in dialog, u can make a 3 textView
TV1, TV2, TV3, let me write the code for you

Comment: i just change the code again, maybe help, im putting the setValue on numberpicker

Comment: remove the gram = np1.getValue(), thats a problem maker

Comment: yes, the value successfully set to picker. Thanks for help. but its not converting correct value in case of 4 digit value. e.g: i set 9999.9999 1st time, it shows 10089.990234375

Comment: okay, let me test the code on android studio, i'll check the problem.

Comment: heres your problem

gw = grams+(mgrams/100f);


it must be

gw = grams+(((double)mgrams)/10000);
.


please upvote and accept the answer if its help, thank you. Cheers~

Comment: Thanks Kevin. i have done with my issue. Thanks for the assistance.

Answer (score 0):

use following code i think your problem solve

```
 public void goldWeight() {
    final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(HomeActivity.this);
    dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_LEFT_ICON);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.testting);
    dialog.setTitle("GOLD WEIGHT[Grams]");
    dialog.setCancelable(true);
    final NumberPicker np1 = (NumberPicker) dialog.findViewById(R.id.grm);
    np1.setMaxValue(9999);
    np1.setMinValue(0000);
    final NumberPicker np2 = (NumberPicker) dialog.findViewById(R.id.mgrm);
    np2.setMaxValue(9999);
    np2.setMinValue(0000);
    Button btnOK = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.btnDialog);
    btnOK.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            int grams = np1.getValue();
            int mgrams = np2.getValue();
            double gw = grams + (mgrams / 100f);
            TextView TV2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
            TV2.setText("" + gw);
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });

    dialog.show();
}
```

change your gold_w_grm XML file Like:

```
<NumberPicker
    android:id="@+id/grm"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
    android:layout_weight="1" />
<NumberPicker
    android:id="@+id/mgrm"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="120dp"
    android:layout_weight="1" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/btnDialog"
    android:text="OK"/>
```

Comment: this might work, because maybe the problem was getting the value of the number picker and computing it `gw = grams+(mgrams/100f);` happens in the same time. that is why it returns no value.

Comment: that's why you have to use dialog button click Listener and add gw = grams + (mgrams / 100f);  in  listener OnClick Method same like my answer

Comment: yes, it looks like it's working somehow. but app crashing when i click on OK button. an when click out side the dialog box, nothing happens except dialog disappear

Comment: TextView TV2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.UserGoldWeight);

Comment: you have to bind TextView with your id